# Qt Mobility Document Gallery API : does it work on S60 5th edition?

Tags: qt, qt-mobility, s60-5th-edition

I am trying to use Document Gallery api on Nokia 5800 and am getting a run-time error - "connection to gallery is broken". I read on Qt Mobility 1.1 reference doc that document gallery backend for S60 3.1, 3.2, and 5.0 is not enabled in pre-built packages.
What does this mean .."in pre-built packages" ? Is there a way to make it work ?

Would appreciate if someone can help.Thanks.